# python3 タプルを空白区切りで出力したい

Tags: python, python3

タプルの値を空白区切りで出力したいです。以下のような書き方をしていたのですが、何かもっといい書き方はないでしょうか？
期待する出力
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7

```
data = [(3,2,1), (6,5,4), (9,8,7)]

for i in data:
　　　　for j in range(3):
    　　　　print(str(i[j]) + ' ',end = '')
　　　　print()
```

Comment: いくつか回答が投稿されておりますので、もしよければ[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？　また、回答が不満足なのであれば、質問文に情報を追記することもできます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

print関数に*で引数展開で。（セパレータはデフォルトの空白文字でよい）

```
data = [(3,2,1), (6,5,4), (9,8,7)]
[print(*i) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in data:
     print(' '.join(str(j) for j in i))
```

か

```
for i in data:
     print(' '.join(map(str, i)))
```

でしょうね。

（これ以上行数を減らそうとするのはきっとやりすぎ）

Answer (score 3):

これでどうでしょう

```
>>> data = [(3,2,1), (6,5,4), (9,8,7)]
>>> for i in data:
...     print(' '.join([str(j) for j in i]))
... 
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7
```